# Writing tests with selenium and unittest Python

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

I am writing a simple sign in test using unittest and selenium.

I would like to know how does Unittest know if a test has failed or not? I want to print "Pass" in my terminal if the sign in was successful and "Fail" if there was an error, like incorrect password.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
class SignIn(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = driver
    self.driver.get('https://example')

def test_sign_in(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('user[email]').send_keys('example')
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('user[password]').send_keys('example')
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('commit').click()


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Comment: There are asserts, why don't you make use of them ?

Comment: How would I implement that ? Ive tried adding 'assert True' at the end, but it does not fail the test if the user failed to sign in. @cruisepandey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user Asserts,

Let's say once you are logged in, you will either see dashboard or welcome screen, right ?

You need to assert them like below :

```
try:
    assert "Expected_message_here" in driver.find_element_by_xpath('welcome page xpath here').text
except:
    print("looks like a failure")
    pass
```

This links contains all the asserts [click here](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Python_unittest_Assertions.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)

and I would suggest you to have a different function to validate fail scenarios.

you can [refer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) here also

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
If there's any successful sign-in message once the user is logged in, you can use a simple `if-else` statement. You may use the below patch of code

```
def test_sign_in(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('user[email]').send_keys('example')
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('user[password]').send_keys('example')
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('commit').click()
    success_msg=find_element_by_xpath('{{xpath of the success message}}')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,success_msg))
    if success_msg:
       print("Successfully logged in")
    else:
       print("Unsuccessful")
```

Method 2:
You may use a `Try Except` block.

```
def test_sign_in(self):
    try:
      self.driver.find_element_by_name('user[email]').send_keys('example')
      self.driver.find_element_by_name('user[password]').send_keys('example')
      self.driver.find_element_by_name('commit').click()
      print("Successfully logged in")
    except:
      print("An exception occurred")
```

The above samples are raw code. Correct the identation, typos etc. Try it out and let me know if it worked for you! Cheers.

Comment: I tried the second method and its exactly what I needed. Thank you ! @LibinThomas

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that its going to print successful even if it wasnt. There is no success message either. It just logs you in. Is there a way for me to do if the page redirects, print('Success') @LibinThomas